# Sublime 3 missing package manager

Tags: sublimetext3, package-control

I've just done a clean install of Sublime 3 on a mid-2010 iMac.  For some reason I don't understand, Package Manager is missing.

I've checked the user settings and nothing there is overriding this. Can anyone please suggest how I can make Package Manger available?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have to install it again, https://packagecontrol.io/installation